# Filtering datagridview using multiple controls

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Sqllite database and filtering a datagridview using five comboboxes and its working fine but my problem is when I dont select value in any of the combobox it does'nt work coz I am using AND and if I'll use OR it'll not give me desired result coz I want to filter using all the selected values in the combobox.
My code is as follows:

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
        string voterlist = "select * from voters";
        DataTable dt = Database.myAdapter(voterlist);
        dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("consname= '{0}' AND area = '{1}' AND pollingstn = '{2}' AND wardno = '{3}' AND policestn = '{4}'", combo_consname.SelectedItem, combo_Area.SelectedItem, combo_Polling.SelectedItem, combo_Ward.SelectedItem, combo_Police.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, in case you want to allow users to do not apply any filtering you should not set the `RowFilter` property when at least one of the `ComboBox` has no selected item or depending on the feature you want to provide, you can construct the `RowFilter` by appending:

```
" AND columnX = '" + yourValue + "'"
```

one by one and only when yourValue is a non null and not empty string.

of course you do not have to start the `RowFilter` string with an `AND`

Comment: thank you so much.. I've constructed the rowfilter by appending and now it works excellent..